# What Field to Use for Height?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

What field do you think is suitable for asking for someone's height, preferably in the format: ft' inches? I thought about decimal or integer fields, but asking for someone's height in inches or cm seems unintuitive and confusing. Should I use a string field? If so, how do I verify that the input is in the format of something like 5'6 or 6'0? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody already asked this question on [UX Stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10256/whats-the-best-and-most-intuitive-way-to-have-a-user-enter-a-height-value-in-fe).

If you want keep your form "simple" you can use TextField and Regexp validator with WTForms :

```
height = TextField('height', [
    validators.Regexp('[3-7]\'\d{1,2}', message='Wrong height'),
])
```